# Keycloak and nodeJS : Unable to refresh with expired refresh token

Tags: node.js, authentication, web, openid, keycloak

**EDIT : I've set a server on a vm, without Docker, and everything worked well, it looks like VM+Docker is too much layer.**

I have a node backend, with a route protected with :

```js
app.get('/api/user', keycloak.protect(), function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'This is an USER endpoint payload' });
});
```

I have this keycloak.json :

```
{
  "realm": "MyRealm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://keycloak.com:8008/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "sso_agt",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

When I use this route, i'm redirected to the auth page. When i'm logged, it redirects me to the right url, but I have denied access, with this error in npm console :

```sh
Could not obtain grant code: Error: Unable to refresh with expired refresh token
```

In my keycloak console, i have a WARN type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR

I run keycloak with docker, on a Ubuntu Server VM.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens are no-expiration passwords, when combined with the clientId and client service allow for the generation of actual access tokens. Once a refresh token is marked as invalid, there is no way to get a new one without navigating the user through implicit login flow with the scope: `offline` set.

Comment: That's really strange then because immediatelly after i connect, my refresh token is expired. I really don't get the way to fix it since, even if I navigate the user through a login flow, his token expires.

Answer (score 0):

I've set a server on a vm, without Docker, and everything worked well, it looks like VM+Docker is too much layer.